# Website won't update in browser without Ctrl + F5

Tags: html, css, refresh

I'm running a basic website with just HTML and CSS. Whenever I push new files to the website, the new files won't show up in the browser until I do a CTRL + F5 (hard refresh). Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you using caching techniques?

Comment: So just do a "hard refresh"... big deal.

Comment: @Sparky672: He can "hard-refresh" ... but he can't tell/force his visitors to "hard-refresh" too. Visitors who are coming back to the site will still see the "old" files.

Comment: @Aziz, his visitors are no different than anyone else's and for a multitude of reasons will likely not have to do any refresh to see the latest files.

Comment: @Aziz, this is the comments section, not a discussion forum... if you cannot understand my two simple comments, there's nothing further to say.

Comment: @Sparky672: alright .. let me explain this in clear words: ScoWalt is uploading new page to his website. He hits refresh (F5) in the browser several times, but the new page does not appear and he still sees the old one. He does a "hard-refresh", and *bingo!*, the new page appears. ScoWalt is asking why wasn't the normal refresh showing the new page. Why is he asking? because ScoWalt worries that his site visitors will face the same problem and still see the old page instead of the new one (since none of them will do a "hard-refresh"). ScoWalt wants to understand the reasons for that! Got it?

Comment: @Aziz, You're a mind-reader... ScoWalt never mentions anything concerning his visitors' experience.  It's only _your assumption_ that this is not all about his own convenience during development.  Furthermore, browser caching depends on the browser (among other things) and is hardly a _permanent_ or persistent condition requiring extraordinary measures.  (Maybe he should be using ajax to dynamically update content if it's critical or changing that often.)

Comment: @Sparky672: OK. I agree that I made few assumptions that were never part of the question, but those assumptions are more likely to be true than any other assumptions (at least this is my opinion). Anyway, Thanks for sharing your point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your **browser is caching** the content of your website when you visit it. The next time you visit, it will show the local, cached copy (unless you "hard-refresh" it).

Check if you have any [cache-related meta tags](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-meta-expires.html) in your pages, and see if using a [no-cache tag](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) would help.

Comment: Adding the meta tag described in your second link worked! Strangely, I had a similar tag in my code previously, but using the one in this link worked...

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must put this in your head section :

```
<meta content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for dev purposes I would consider a tool like live reload which will update your browser as you update your files.  http://livereload.com/